# How to show that $P(B_1>0, B_2<0)= P(B_1>0)P(B_2-B_1 <0) P(|B_2 - B_1| > |B_1|)$?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, conditional-probability

The following is an interview question from Zhou Xinfeng's book entitled 'A Practical Guide to Quantitative Finance Interview'.

> Question: Let $B_t$ be a Brownian motion. What is the probability that $B_1 > 0$ and $B_2 < 0$?

The author provided two methods, first uses double integral and second uses independence and conditional probability. The following is the second approach.

$$P(B_1>0, B_2<0) = P(B_1>0)P(B_2-B_1 <0) P(|B_2 - B_1| > |B_1|) = \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{8}.$$

I do not understand how the author decompose $P(B_1>0, B_2<0)$ into $P(B_1>0)P(B_2-B_1 <0) P(|B_2 - B_1| > |B_1|).$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two aspects to this; I don't know which aspect you have trouble with.

**Logic:**

$$B_1 > 0 \cap B_2 < 0 \iff B_1 > 0 \cap B_2 - B_1 < 0 \cap |B_2 - B_1| > |B_1|$$

The latter two RHS terms literally say, between $t=1$ to $2$, you have to have a net leftward movement, and by an absolute distance bigger than the rightward movement between $t=0$ and $1$ (in order to end up $B_2 < 0$).  I am not sure I can explain better than this.

**Probability:** From the logic formula above, we have:

$$P(B_1 > 0 \cap B_2 < 0) = P( B_1 > 0 \cap B_2 - B_1 < 0 \cap |B_2 - B_1| > |B_1|)$$

So next we need to argue that the three RHS terms are mutually independent.  This comes from:

- $X_1 = B_1$ and $X_2 = (B_2 - B_1)$ are independent because they don't overlap in time
- $Sign(X_j)$ and $|X_j|$ are independent, because the Brownian motion is unbiased (symmetric about $0$).
- Therefore all four of $Sign(B_1), |B_1|, Sign(B_2 - B_1), |B_2 - B_1|$ are mutually independent.

Now realizing that $B_1 > 0 \iff Sign(B_1) = +1$ etc allows us to break the three terms of the RHS apart.

$$P( B_1 > 0 \cap B_2 - B_1 < 0 \cap |B_2 - B_1| > |B_1|) \\
= P( B_1 > 0) ~~P(B_2 - B_1 < 0) ~~P(|B_2 - B_1| > |B_1|)$$
The first two terms each equals $1/2$ because of the Brownian motion being unbiased (symmetric about $0$), and the last term equals $1/2$ because $|B_1|$ and $|B_2 - B_1|$ are i.i.d. variables (and they're equal with prob $0$).

Answer (score 2):

Use the independence of $B_1$ and $B_2-B_1$ along with the identity
\begin{align}
\{B_1>0,B_2<0\}&=\{B_1>0,B_2-B_1<0,B_1-B_2>B_1\}\\
&=\{B_1>0,B_2-B_1<0,|B_2-B_1|>|B_1|\}
\end{align}

Comment: How do you obtain the first equality and how do we proceed with probability?

Comment: Notice that $B_2<0$ iff $B_1-B_2 > B_1$. Also, if $B_1>0$ and $B_2<0$, then $B_2-B_1<B_2<0$.  As for the how to get the probabilities, you may use the following: If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then for any nice function $f(X,Y)$, $E(f(X,Y)]= E[h(X)]$ where $h(x)=E[f(x,Y)]$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\omega \in  \{B_1>0 \}\ \cap \{ B_2<0 \}.$ Let's think about the path $t \rightarrow B_t(\omega)$ as a continuous function such that $B_0(\omega)=0.$ We have the time in the x-axis and  $B_t(\omega)$ in the y-axis. If $B_t(\omega)$ traveled $B_1(\omega)>0$ units from $t=0$ to $t=1$, then for $B_2(\omega)$ to be negative, the distance $|B_2(\omega)-B_1(\omega) |$ traveled over the y-axis from $t=1$ to $t=2$ must have been greater than the distance $|B_1(\omega)|$ traveled from $t=0$ to $t=1.$ There are 2 possibilities equally provable$_{(*)}$  for the distance $|B_2(\omega)-B_1(\omega) |$ to be greater than the distance $|B_1(\omega)|$. One possibility is that $B_2(\omega)$ ended above $B_1(\omega),$ (i.e $B_2(\omega)>B_1(\omega)$), the other one is that it ended below (i.e $B_2(\omega)<B_1(\omega)$). Obviously, if it ended above, it can't be $B_2(\omega)<0,$ (since $B_1(\omega)>0$) so it has to be $B_2(\omega)<B_1(\omega)$. So $\omega \in \{B_1>0 \} \cap \{ |B_2-B_1|>|B_1| \} \cap \{ B_2<B_1 \}.$ The reverse can be proven similarly.

(*) the two possibilities are equally probable because the Brownian motion is a Markov process.

Since $B_2-B_1$ is independent from $B_1$, these last three sets are independent,  so you can multiply the probabilities.

Comment: As it is an interview question, I think there should be an intuitive way to obtain the equality?

Comment: That's way I explained it the way I did, to show the intuition behind. If $B_2(\omega)$ is negative after $B_1(\omega)$ was positive, it means that you had to travel from $t=1$ to $t=2$ more distance (i.e $|B_2(\omega)-B_1(\omega)|$) than you traveled from $t=0$ to $t=1$. The first trip until t=1 you went up (above 0) so now you have to travel at least that distance in one direction (it can be up or down) to have the chance that $B_2(\omega)$ is negative.

Comment: but "up" doesn't make sense because it would be $B_2(\omega)>B_1(\omega)>0,$ and we know it is $B_2(\omega)<0$ so it must be "down", (i.e. $B_2(\omega)< B_1(\omega)$).

Answer (score 1):

$P(B_1 > 0 \land B_2 < 0 ) = P(B_1 > 0)P(B_2<0 | B_1 > 0)$

$B_1-B_0 = B_1 \thicksim \mathcal N(0, 1)$

$B_2-B_1=N \thicksim \mathcal N(0, 1)$

$P(B_2<0 | B_1 > 0) = P(B_2-B_1<B_1 | B_1 > 0) = P(N<B_1 | B_1 > 0)$ because we need to jump from positive value to negative value so if in step 1 we got value $x>0$ now in step 2 we need to make jump by value smaller than $-x$ (negative and bigger in terms of absolute values)

$P(N<B_1 | B_1 > 0) = P(N<0)P(|N| > |B_1|) = P(B_2-B_1 < 0)P(|B_2-B_1| > |B_1|)$

*answer probably needs a bit of polishing